# Profile integer values from Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have written a script that loop trough several `matrices`.
The output I am getting looks like this:

```
10,40,50
20,60,50,80
30,50,70,110
30,70,110
```

and so on...

What I want to do is to count how many unique profiles there exist, if one matrix contain `10,40,50` it will be counted as one profile labeled (10,40,50) when if it will find another matrix that is exactly the same (10,40,50) it should print: 10,40,50 found 2 time and so on iteratively.

So to sum it up, I have a script that runs trough matrices. They contain of different values that repeat themselves from time to time, I want to count all existent unique profiles. Let say we input this:

```
10,40,50
10,40,50
10,40,50
30,50,70,110
20,60,50,80
30,50,70,110
10,40,50
10,40,50
```

The output should be (the counting could be outputted however):

```
10,40,50 found 5 time

20,60,50,80 found 1 time

30,50,70,110 found 2 time
```

Help is very, very much appreciated, doing this for a hobby project.

Edit: It's not a cell array I am using, it is a <1x500> vector I am looping trough.

Answer (score 1):

(It's a pity that the `unique` function doesn't work on a cell array of numeric vectors.)

You can do it as follows:

```
x = { [10,40,50];
      [10,40,50]
      [10,40,50];
      [30,50,70,110];
      [20,60,50,80];
      [30,50,70,110];
      [10,40,50];
      [10,40,50] };
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(x)); % indices of all pairs
m = cellfun(@isequal, x(ii), x(jj)); % all pairwise comparisons
[u, v] = unique(m, 'rows', 'stable'); % unique rows, and their indices
count = sum(u,2); % result: number of repetitions
unique_x = x(v); % result: unique vectors
```

This gives

```
>> celldisp(unique_x)
unique_x{1} =
    10    40    50
unique_x{2} =
    30    50    70   110
unique_x{3} =
    20    60    50    80
>> count
count =
     5
     2
     1
```

To display with the desired format:

```
for n = 1:numel(unique_x)
    disp([mat2str(unique_x{n}) ' found ' num2str(count(n)) ' time(s)'])
end
```

prints

```
[10 40 50] found 5 time(s)
[30 50 70 110] found 2 time(s)
[20 60 50 80] found 1 time(s)
```

If the results are obtained in a loop: collect them into a cell array and then apply the above:

```
x = cell(1,num_iter); % preallocate if possible
for iter_index = 1:num_iter
    % Do stuff that gives a vector iter_result as a result
    x{iter_index} = iter_result;
end
% Now apply above code to x
```

Comment: How could I use this in my script to display the output like this (with disp):

10,40,50 found 5 time

20,60,50,80 found 1 time

30,50,70,110 found 2 time

Comment: @J.Smith That's just a simple loop. See edited answer

Comment: How would you do if its not a cell array but only 1 column vectors?

Comment: Do you mean separate variables, say `a`, `b`, `c`? Put them in a cell array so you can loop over it: `x = {a b c}` Be sure to specify your question more clearly next time

Comment: Just did that, but for each iteration it count a found profile as 1 and never increase.

Comment: The thing is that the values from each matrix are "coming in" per iteration =/

Comment: So... store the result of each iteration into the cell array. Something like `x{iter_index} = iter_result;` So after the last iteration you can apply my code

Comment: I appreciate your help very much @Luis Mendo
I am a total newbie with matlab, could you please update your answer and show how the result could be saved into the cell array, I am getting confused with ´x{iter_index} = iter_result;´

Comment: this gives me: Undefined function or variable 'num_iter'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your output of your script is a cell array, since my kind of ad-hoc answer is based on this assumption. So, if the output of your script is:

```
output = {[10,40,50];
          [10,40,50];
          [10,40,50];
          [30,50,70,110];
          [20,60,50,80];
          [30,50,70,110];
          [10,40,50];
          [10,40,50]};
```

We can convert your output in string format. Lame, but works :) :

```
tmp = cellfun(@num2str,output,'UniformOutput',false);
```

And then we use `unique` function:

```
[a,b,c]=unique(tmp);
```

Where `a` is the unique strings of `tmp`, `b` is the first occurrence of the string in tmp and `c` shows which element in `tmp` corresponds to which element in `a`, i.e. maps `tmp` onto `a`. All we have to do now is to count how many `1`-s, `2`-s, `3`-s etc  in the vector `c`. I prefer to use a simple loop for this purpose:

```
for k = 1:length(b)
    n(k) = nnz(c == k);
    disp(['[',a{k},'] found ',num2str(n(k)),' time(s)'])
end
```

So, the final output is:

```
[10  40  50] found 5 time(s)
[20  60  50  80] found 1 time(s)
[30   50   70  110] found 2 time(s)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: How would you do if its not a cell array but only 1 column vectors?

Comment: @J.Smith I'd convert the output to cell array :)

Answer (score 0):

```
output = {[10,40,50];
      [10,40,50];
      [10,40,50];
      [30,50,70,110];
      [20,60,50,80];
      [30,50,70,110];
      [10,40,50];
      [10,40,50]};
tmp = cellfun(@num2str,output,'UniformOutput',false); % number to string
[a,~,c] = unique(tmp); % find unique profiles and index from tmp to a
count = accumarray(c,1); % count same index in c
```

Then

```
for k = 1 : length(a)
    fprintf('[ %s ] found %d time(s)\n',a{k},count(k));
end
```

shows the same message with other answers.

Comment: How could this be used if the output is not a cell array? It is only vectors <1x500> that I loop trough a script.

Comment: what do you mean by **<1x500>**? You mean output is just single vector? Then you need to know the size of each profile or it should be much trickier

Comment: Yes, just a single vector.